# large amount of data in Azure SQL > U-SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, u-sql

I am trying to find the best way to process in U-SQL a query that produces 450 millions rows. I use DataFactory V2 (pipeline) - USQL for transformation

The problem : it takes an eternity to extract it into a csv file and to inject it back to the Azure SQL DB

I wanted to know if it is possible to query directly the Azure database with U-SQL and after injecting the result directly to the Azure DB?
it would be faster instead of generating CSV as an imput and a CSV as an output...

thanks

Comment: `it takes an eternity to extract it into a csv file and to inject it back to the Azure SQL DB` are you seeing issues when extracting data /injecting data into azure db

Comment: no issues just it is not possible to wait so long.